# repeated patterns in time series graphs

Tags: python, time-series

Can someone recommend a python package that would be good for

1. Identifying repeated shapes in a time series graph?
2. Given the index and length of a shape in a graph (say, identified in 1), return the position and size of similar shapes in a graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like for 1: Matrix Profile
http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/MatrixProfile.html
Where there's sample Matlab code to visualise and output the top 3 motifs in your time series.

For 2: MASS: Mueen's Algorithm for Similarity Search
http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mueen/FastestSimilaritySearch.html
Where there's a Matlab function to perform the similarity search.

A python implementation of an earlier version of the algorithm used by 1. https://github.com/rob-med/owlpy

I'll need to raise a separate question regarding Matlab code I think to use the results of 1 on 2.  But I think the above answers my original question.